# If X be a Hilbert space, How can write above condition?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

For points $p,q,r,s\in X$,
$$(d(r,p)‎\leq‎ d(p,s)\ \&\ d(r,q) \leq‎ d(q,s))\Rightarrow‎ d(r,m)\leq‎ d(m,s)$$
for any point $m$ in the segment $[x,y]$.
\How is this condition for Hilbert spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by: "How is this condition for Hilbert spaces?"

Comment: If $X$ be a Hilbert space, How can write above condition?

Comment: How are x and y connected to p and q? What is a segment in a general metric space?

Comment: sorry, $x=p , y=q$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that
$$
0\le \|s-m\|^2-\|r-m\|^2=\langle s-r, r+s-2m\rangle
$$
where $m=(1-λ)p+λq$ and the inequality is known as true for $m=p$ and $m=q$. But since $λ\in[0,1]$, both factors $λ$ and $(1-λ)$ are positive and the inequality follows as the convex combination of the known inequalities.